# When deleting file value from a loop array, it messes up the container background - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

**[Here is the bug](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stpwi2?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**
I loop the input files with each container.  Then set the background image from the file input of its children.

```
    <div class="thumbnailHolder" *ngFor="let colImage of proPub.image ;let y = index trackBy: trackByFn" [attr.data-index]="y">
      <span class="removeImage" (click)="deleteNewImageColour($event,i,y)">X</span>
      <input
        class="imaged" type="file" name="" required="required"
        [(ngModel)]="productPublish[i].image[y]" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event, i, y)"
      />
    </div>
```

If I have ten images which are pushed to an array when added, the `fileChangeEvent` will set the background image to its container.

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
  imageSrc = e.target['result'];
  fileInput.srcElement.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageSrc + ')';
};
```

However, if I delete an array, let's say: `indexOf 9`,

```
  image.splice(y, 1)
```

It will mess up the loop for the background image. The background image is not set for its correct input file as expected.

And if I delete it by removing the source element, it won't delete the array.

```
 srcElement.parentElement.remove()
```

It works fine if I combine the two methods.  But it only deletes the last array or element.  If I do it with any array besides the last array then it will delete two things simultaneously(at the same time), first the array and then the element of which will delete the loop two times.

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: can you referred to style.background directly in your html, some like <div [ngStyle]="{'backgroundImage':image[i]}"/> or even <div [style.backgroundImage]="image[i]?

Comment: I have tried that, but the bugs seems like in the dom itself.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5pgiy Hope that fixes your problem. 
I took liberty to remove some non-essential things like data-index attributes.

Angular abstracts away DOM modifications so you shouldn't modify nodes directly. Otherwise results are random-ish like in your example.

Moreover, using trackBy isn't meant to be used like that. It's optimization technique to prevent superfluous rendering of unchanged elements. Your implementation says that "array elements never change indices" and later you change them by using splice.